# Doxygen: I need to save multiple versions of the API, such as V1.0V1.1... How to create my page

Tags: doxygen

I have already created a doxygen document,

but now I have created many versions such as v1.0, V1.1, V1.2.

What method can I use to display all of these versions?

I hope it is a dropdown list box, and when users choose different versions, the displayed documents will also be different

Comment: Doxygen has no direct feature for this but you can create a dedicated header.html (setting `HTML_HEADER`). An example where I've this has been done is https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/general_intro.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I noticed that you have created a fixed menu bar above, which remains unchanged when the drop-down list box is selected.